# TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len() with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok so im making a code to calculate equations of motion in physics. I have 5 entry boxes that are giving variables and when 1 of them isn't filled i get an error. So I'm trying to implement a system where it checks if all boxes are filled. If they arent it will give them an error popup. Im doing this by checking the len() of what is gotten from the boxes. However, I get the error. TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len() 
Line 44 gives me the error.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter
from tkinter import font as tkFont
from tkinter import messagebox

Window = Tk()
Window.title("SUVAT Calculator")

A = Label(text="SUVAT calculator.")
A.config(font=("Segoe Print", 25))
A.pack()
B = Label(text="Please enter values. Leave 0 for unknowns")
B.config(font=("Segoe Print", 12))
B.pack()

ST = 0
UT = 0
VT = 0
AT = 0
TT = 0
S = 0
U = 0
V = 0
A = 0
T = 0

SP9 = tkFont.Font(family='Segoe Print', size=9)

SValues = Frame(Window)
SValues.pack()
UValues = Frame(Window)
UValues.pack()
VValues = Frame(Window)
VValues.pack()
AValues = Frame(Window)
AValues.pack()
TValues = Frame(Window)
TValues.pack()

def Calculate ():
    global S, U, V, A, T
    global SEntry, UEntry, VEntry, AEntry, TEntry
    if len(SEntry.get) or len(UEntry.get) or len(VEntry.get) or len(AEntry.get) or len(TEntry.get) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning(Title="Error", text="There are incomplete fields!")
    ST = float(SEntry.get())
    UT = float(UEntry.get())
    VT = float(VEntry.get())
    AT = float(AEntry.get())
    TT = float(TEntry.get())
    S = float(ST)
    U = float(UT)
    V = float(VT)
    A = float(AT)
    T = float(TT)
    if (S == 0) and (V == 0):
        S = ((V + U) * T) / 2
        V = U + (A * T)
        A = ((V - U) / T)
    if (S == 0) and (A == 0):
        S = ((V + U) * T) / 2
        A = (V - U) / T
    if (S == 0) and (T == 0):
        S = (V ^ 2 - U ^ 2) / (2 * A)
        T = (V - u) / A
    if (S == 0) and (U == 0):
        S = (V * T) - (0.5 * A * (T ^ 2))
        U = V - (A * T)
    if (A == 0) and (U == 0):
        pass



SLabel = Label(SValues, text="Displacement:")
SLabel.config(font=("Segoe Print", 10))
SLabel.pack(side = LEFT)
SEntry = Entry(SValues, bg="Light Grey")
SEntry.pack(side = RIGHT)

ULabel = Label(UValues, text="Initial velocity:")
ULabel.config(font=("Segoe Print", 10))
ULabel.pack(side = LEFT)
UEntry = Entry(UValues, bg="Light Grey")
UEntry.pack(side = RIGHT)

VLabel = Label(VValues, text="Final Velocity:")
VLabel.config(font=("Segoe Print", 10))
VLabel.pack(side = LEFT)
VEntry = Entry(VValues, bg="Light Grey")
VEntry.pack(side = RIGHT)

ALabel = Label(AValues, text="Acceleration:")
ALabel.config(font=("Segoe Print", 10))
ALabel.pack(side = LEFT)
AEntry = Entry(AValues, bg="Light Grey")
AEntry.pack(side = RIGHT)

TLabel = Label(TValues, text="Time:")
TLabel.config(font=("Segoe Print", 10))
TLabel.pack(side = LEFT)
TEntry = Entry(TValues, bg="Light Grey")
TEntry.pack(side = RIGHT)

Submit = Button(Window, command=Calculate, text="Calculate", font=SP9)
Submit.pack()
```

Comment: It should be `SEntry.get()` and same for the others too. You forgot `()`. Your `messagebox` keyword arguments are wrong, it should be `title` and `message`. And your `if` statement is wrong too. It should be `if len(SEntry.get())==0 or len(UEntry.get())==0 or ......len(TEntry.get()) == 0:`. And you have an undefined variable(`u`) at line 65.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parenthesis after **get**, and you would also need to change that if statement since the way it is now, it will always return True.

Comment: You would also need to change "Title" and "text" options to "title" and "message" in messagebox.showwarning. You also have one lowercase 'u' at line 65, which I guess is supposed to be uppercase.

Comment: I think you should also mention about the `if` statements.

Comment: This works, however i still get the same error about this line.

Comment: ST = float(SEntry.get())

Comment: @Ben711Gaming If your input is non integers, then obviously it will give error.

Comment: @CoolCloud Im trying to make something that gives the messagebox if not all 5 boxes are filled.

Comment: @ben711gaming follow what i said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty much simple. Just replace this.

```
if len(SEntry.get) or len(UEntry.get) or len(VEntry.get) or len(AEntry.get) or len(TEntry.get) == 0:
```

With this

```
if len(SEntry.get()) or len(UEntry.get()) or len(VEntry.get()) or len(AEntry.get()) or len(TEntry.get()) == 0:
```

> Explanation:
> For getting the value of string var you must use the function .get() not .get
> So when you use .get its give `<bound method StringVar.get of <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x02E3AB10>>` and its a method. So when you use it in len() It gives
> TypeError because len() function gives length of a string, int or float etc. but not of method like this.
> Hope You Got this. :)